# Using Purrr to export a list

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a list which contains sub tables. I want to be able to use `purrr` to export the tables individually with the name of the item in the list - in the case below i would get three files with each plant named with today's date

```
library('purrr')
library('tidyverse')

mytest <- iris
mylist <- split(mytest,f = mytest$Species)
names(mylist)

# basically pseudo code for explanation purposes
write_excel_csv(mylist[1], names(mylist[1]))
```

I'm only learning how to use it effectively at the moment so any help with the explanation and why you did it this way would be great

I get that i could write a for loop to just iterate through the list but i want to use this as a learning experience to start into `purrr`

Thank you for your time

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks so much @nrussell. Please submit it as an answer and i will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` from base R will work fine for something like this:

```
Map(write.csv, mylist, sprintf("%s-%s.csv", names(mylist), Sys.Date()))
list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
# [1] "setosa-2017-02-13.csv"     "versicolor-2017-02-13.csv" "virginica-2017-02-13.csv"
```

Alternatively, `walk2` (and probably several other functions in `purrr`) could be used in this manner.